# variable is undefined, yet clearly defined in my constructor C++

Tags: c++, static, lnk2019

I have a C++ assignment that requires me to create a class called `Tips`, that:

- has a single member variable, `float taxRate`
- has two constructors, a default that sets `taxRate` to `.65`, and a one parameter constructor, that sets `taxRate` to whatever float the user enters in my `tipMain.cpp` file.
- has only one function, `computeTip`, that accepts two arguments: `totBill` and `tipRate`, both `float`s that must calculate the before-tax meal cost, and return the tip based on that value and the desired tip rate.

My issue occurs when I attempt to use taxRate inside the computeTip function.

If I use `taxRate`, `computeTip` doesn't understand the value of `taxRate`, stating it is undefined, and even if I do specify `tips::taxRate`, before I even compile Visual Studio states

> Error: a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object.

I vaguely understand this error, but even if I declare `taxRate` to be static in my .h file, I get LNK2019 errors.

Tips.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <float.h>
#include "Tips.h"

using namespace std;

Tips::Tips()
{
    taxRate = 0.65;
}

Tips::Tips(float a)
{
    taxRate = a;
}

float computeTip(float totBill, float tipRate)
{
    float mealOnly = 0;
    mealOnly = (totBill/taxRate);       //written both ways to show errors. taxRate undefined here.
    mealOnly = (totBill/Tips::taxRate); //Error: a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object
    return (mealOnly * tipRate);

}
```

Tips.h

```
#ifndef Tips_H
#define Tips_H
#include <float.h>

using namespace std;

class Tips
{
public:
    Tips();
    Tips(float);
    float computeTip(float, float, float);
    float taxRate;
};
#endif
```

and my tipMain.cpp

```
#include "Tips.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>


using namespace std;

float tax;
float meal;
float tip;
void tipProcessor();

int main()
{
    char entry;
    int toggle = 1;
    cout << "Welcome to the Gratuity Calculator!" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    while (toggle != 0)
    {
        cout << "Enter 1 to calculate tip." << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Enter 2 to exit." << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Entry: ";
        cin >> entry;
        switch (entry)
        {
        case '1': 
            tipProcessor();
            break;
        case '2': 
            toggle = 0;
            break;
        default: 
            cout << "Enter 1 or 2." << endl;
            cout << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
void tipProcessor()
{
    cout << "Enter bill total: ";
    cin >> meal;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter tax rate: ";
    cin >> tax;
    cout << endl;
    Tips thisTip(tax);
    cout << "Enter tip percent: ";
    cin >> tip;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Tip is $" << setprecision(4) << thisTip.computeTip(meal, tip, thisTip.taxRate) << "." << endl;
    cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You use

```
float computeTip(float totBill, float tipRate)
```

But it should be:

```
float Tips::computeTip(float totBill, float tipRate)
```

in the implementation. Also you should hide your data members.

Comment: Thank you and all those below you!  I knew it was going to be something simple.  I swear I'm not special.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining `computeTip()` as global function, therefore only public static member access is possible.  Define as `float Tips::computeTip(float ...)` and it should compile.

Answer (score 0):

You've not specified that `computeTip` is a method of `Tips`. Change it to this:

```
float Tips::computeTip(float totBill, float tipRate)
{
    float mealOnly = 0;
    mealOnly = (totBill/taxRate);
    return (mealOnly * tipRate);
}
```

And all should be well.

Answer (score 0):

Your method declaration and and method definition do not have the same signature. In your header file you indicate that `computeTip` should take 3 `float` arguments, but when you define it in the .cpp file, it only takes two arguments.

This is in addition to what other users suggest, prefixing your function with `Tips::` to indicate that it is part of the `Tips` class and thus should be able to access member variables such as `taxRate`.

Thus your header declaration should look like:

```
float computeTips(float, float);
```

And your method definition should look like

```
float Tips::computeTip(float totBill, float tipRate)
{
...
```